# How to enable multiuser or guest account on Asus ZenPad 10 Z300C with Android 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, multi-user

On other android devices I've used, there was a multiuser feature or guest feature available to allow other people to use the device without altering each others settings or giving them access to each other's accounts.

Is this feature available on the Asus ZenPad 10 (Z300C) running Android 6.0? If so, where is it? It doesn't appear to be available under `settings > accounts`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enabled on [your device](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-206880/)

Workaround for rooted devices discussed on [XDA](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/zenpad-10/help/asus-zenpad-10-z300c-multi-user-t3282624/amp/)

Comment: Google search will show more sites that talk of this feature not being available